# Differential definition

Tags: calculus, analysis

Hi all thanks for your attention.

I have this exercise :

Given $f, g : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ two functions with f differentiable in $0$, $g$ continuous in $0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Prove that $fg$  is differentiable in $0$ and its differential is $g(0)*df(0)$.

I thought in this way : by the definition of differentiability of f, I have $f(0+h)=f(0)+df(0)(h)+o(|h|)$ and by the fact that $g$ is continuous in $0$, I have $g(h) =g(0)$, all this for $h \to 0$.

So if I consider the product of f(0+h) and g(0+h), I obtain

$(f*g)(h)= (f*g)(0)+g(0)*df(0)+g(0)*o(|h|)$

but this last is a $o(|h|)$ so I have

$(f*g)(h) =(f*g) (0) +g(0)*df(0) +o(|h|)$

which is the definition of differentiability of $f*g$.

But I didn't use the fact that $f(0)=0$.

Is it fair this reasoning ? Thanks again :)

Comment: I have bettered your presentation : next time, think at least to enclose your formulas between dollar signs like this `$b^2-4ac$`... and separate your paragraphs by void lines.

Comment: You are mixing together expressions that are only true in the limit as $h \to 0$ with expressions where $h$ has not gone to $0$. This is not allowable. $h$ either goes to $0$ everywhere, or nowhere. Having it go to $0$ in some spots but not others makes assumptions that are not universal. Write out your expressions in terms of $(g(h) - g(0))$, and only at the end do you get to let $h \to 0$ *everywhere*.